# Is this the correct way of drawing a combinatorial circuit based on the disjunctive normal form and logic table?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

**The logic table:**
$$\begin{array}{|c3:c|}\hline
x & y & z & f(x,y,z) \\\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline\end{array}$$

The DNF I came up with based on this table is $f(X,Y,Z) = (X \land Y \land Z) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y \land Z)$

**Here is my attempted solution at a combinatorial circuit:**
Is this the correct way of doing it for this logic table? If not, where did I go wrong?
[image]

Comment: What's the final output gate, it should be a OR-2, but you've got some kind of inverter  ? Other than that, your circuit matches your boolean equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Logic Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate)" diagram is okay for what you have *except* that is not how you draw an "or-gate".

**However**, your function is not okay.   Notice that you have $f(1,1,0) = (1\land 1\land 0)\lor(0\land 0 \land 0)$ which is $0$.   You need it to be $1$.

$$f(X,Y,Z) ~\ne~ (X \land Y \land Z) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y \land Z)$$

It is *close* though.   (*Maybe* a typo?)